# Python count copies in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I am trying to count the copies in my dictionary.

My dictionary

```
{0: 'once', 1: 'twice', 2: 'twice'}
```

My code:

```
def count(self, item):
    """Return the number of copies of item in the bag.

    Return zero if the item doesn't occur in the bag.
    """

    counter = 0
    for key in self.bag:
        if item == item:
            counter = len(self.bag) - 1
    else:
        counter = 0
    print(counter)
    return counter
```

Should return 2 as there are 2 copies and 1 duplicate item.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where `Counter`s come in **real** handy. You can make a `Counter` to keep track of all the values in your dict. It's as simple as:

```
from collections import Counter
temp = {0: 'once', 1: 'twice', 2: 'twice'}
counter = Counter (temp.values())
```

This returns `Counter({'twice': 2, 'once': 1})`.

Now, to find how many copies, you simply take `len (counter)`, and all the duplicates are any entries (keys) with a count (value) of > 1:

```
duplicates = [key for key, count in counter.items() if count > 1]
```

Comment: Hmm ok I think I get it I will try it. Do you think there's away to accomplish the same with out using Counter ?

Comment: Well counter is basically doing what you are behind the scenes, just with some slight improvements (y'know being in C and all), so there's really no reason **not** to use it. If there is tell me and I can help

Comment: No real reason only that I thought my code was very nearly there but just couldn't quite finish it due to my lack of experience. I've also spent a very long time getting it to that point.

Comment: Well in that case, why do you have an `else` block? You don't have a `break` anywhere in your loop (which is what the `else` is for), so `counter` gets set to 0 at the end of the loop, no matter what the result. Other than that your code looks fine (except idk what `self.bag` is)

Comment: ah! thank you. i have fixed it! with using a break after counter = len(self.bag) - 1 and changing my else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy` module.

```
import collections
import copy
cnt = collections.Counter([1,2,3,3,2,4,5,6,7])
def f1(c):
    c[2] = 0
tmp = copy.deepcopy(cnt)
f1(tmp)
```

The `cnt` remains unchanged after the call of `f1`.